# How do I use an OR condition in an exposed filter?

Tags: views

I have a view with more than 10 checkboxes for the multiple selection in exposed form with some field. Using the Drupal exposed filter for the multiple fields make the query of AND, but somehow I need the multiple selections in OR condition.

Is there any way to change the query to use a OR condition?

Answer (score 2):

You can make view filter with OR condition by clicking on **And/Or, Rearrange** link.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we use Drupal `view_query_alter` to add or modify the view's where clause. To add a new WHERE clause we may use `add_where` property. Whenever we use an a`dd_where`, it will create a WHERE clause along with an AND condition. There will be some cases were we need to use OR instead of AND. So if you want to know more about how to use OR clause in `hook_view_query_alter`, read on to know more.

We can use `db_or` to add a new OR condition with `add_where`. For example see the sample code

```
function mymodule_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ('yourviewname' == $view->name && 'page' == $view->current_display) {
    $weight_parent = array(29,31);
    $or = db_or()
    ->condition('taxonomy_term_data_taxonomy_term_hierarchy.weight', 'NULL', 'IS')
    ->condition('taxonomy_term_data_node.weight', $weight_parent, 'IN');
    $query->add_where(1,$or);
  }
}
```